# PIXEL switching to Console after desktop loads, preventing VNC

Tags: remote, vnc, terminal, pixel, desktop

quick question/problem I hope.  I have a Raspberry Pi 3 B+ set up with Debian Jessie and PIXEL.  I set the machine up to run as a VPN server initially and then for kicks installed RetroPie on top.  I also have SSH & VNC servers enabled, and want the machine to boot to the desktop.  I plan to remote back to it from overseas.

I've noticed that when I reboot the machine, it will load the desktop and then switch to TTY1.  There is no failure, it's just console switching.  The problem I get then is if I am away and use VNC to reach-back to the machine it gives a black screen until the machine is physically switched by ctrl+alt+f7 back to the desktop.  How can I either prevent the switch, or remotely trigger a switch to stay on the desktop (I don't think that is possible via SSH...)?  I don't have the machine set up as headless, and VNC is not virtualized.  Is that a better option?  I'm not sure how to set it up in that manner from what I have now.

It may be worth noting I had set up extra-info on the console with a RetroArch add-on/script which prints out system info to the console login like memory use and such before log-in.  I'm not sure if that is somehow grabbing the physical display.

Any help?